# A* algorithm isn't stopping or evaluating neighbours properly

Tags: c++, algorithm, a-star

I'm trying to develop an A* algorithm able to find the path between two points. The idea is having a map represented into a graph where the edges represent streets and the vertexes represent the intersection between two different points.

I'm extracting the data from a txt with this format:

```
4726;"";3293;3294;0.0268074;40;-8.6555719;41.1484438;-8.6556097;41.1486832
```

Each field represents, respectively the id, name, source, target, distance, speed, x1, y1, x2, y2.

This is my vertex class:

```
// VERTEX
template <class T>
class Vertex { //cruzamentos

    T intersect;
    vector<Edge<T> > adj;
    bool visited;
    float distance;
    float time;
    int indegree;       //numero arestas que apontam para este no
    bool processing, closed, inQueue;

public:

    Vertex(T in);

    T getIntersection() const;
    vector<Edge<T> > getAdj() const;

    bool getVisited() const;
    void setVisited(bool v);

    float getDistance() const;
    void setDistance(float d);

    float getTime() const;
    void setTime(float t);

    int getIndegree() const;
    void setIndegree(int i);

    bool addEdge(Edge<T> &edge);
    int findEdge(Vertex<T> &v);     //retorna posicao no vetor adj se existir, se nao -1
    int findEdgeByID(int id);

    Vertex *path;

    float fx;           //Astar

    int findSmallestAdj();          //retorna posicao no vetor adj da aresta mais pequena ligada a este nó
    friend class Graph<T>;
};

template <class T>
struct vertex_greater_than {
    bool operator()(Vertex<T> * a, Vertex<T> * b) const {
        return a->getDistance() > b->getDistance();
    }
};

template <class T>
struct vertex_greater_than_time {
    bool operator()(Vertex<T> * a, Vertex<T> * b) const {
        return a->getTime() > b->getTime();
    }
};

template <class T>
struct vertex_greater_than_fx {
    bool operator()(Vertex<T> * a, Vertex<T> * b) const {
        return a->fx > b->fx;
    }
};
```

This is my edge class:

```
// EDGE
template <class T>
class Edge { // ruas

    Vertex<T> * dest;
    string name;
    float length;
    float vMax;
    static int ID;
    int thisID;

public:
    Edge(Vertex<T> *d, string n, float l, float vm);
    Edge();

    Vertex<T>* getDest() const;
    string getName() const;
    float getLength() const;
    float getVMax() const;
    int getID() const;

    friend class Graph<T>;
    friend class Vertex<T>;
};
```

and my graph class:

```
// GRAPH
template <class T>
class Graph {

    vector<Vertex<T> *> vertexSet;

public:

    Graph();

    vector<Vertex<T> *> getVertexSet() const;
    unsigned int getNumVertex() const;

    int addVertex(const T &in);     //devolve posicao do vetor em que se encontra o vertice, push_back se nao existia e devolve vector.size();
    bool addEdge(const T &sourc, const T &dest, string name, float length, float vm);

    bool removeVertex(const T &in);                         //TODO
    bool removeEdge(const T &source, const T &dest);        //TODO

    void DijkstraShortestPath(const T &start);
    void DijkstraFastestPath(const T &start);

    void aStar(const T &start, const T &goal, bool dist);

    vector<T> getPath(const T &source, const T &dest);

    int findVertex(const T &f);         //pela interseccao
    int getVertexByID(int id);          //pelo id da interseccao

    int getFirstID(int id) {
        for(int i = 0; i < vertexSet.size(); i++) {
            if(vertexSet[i]->getIntersection().getID() == id && vertexSet[i]->getIntersection().getID() >= 0) {
                return vertexSet[i]->getIntersection().getID();
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    friend class Vertex<T>;

};
```

And then I tried to develop an A star algorithm but I'm getting a really weird output:

```
47629
47629
2994
2994
2994
2994
2994
2994
2994
2994
2994
2994
2994
2994
1862
1862
1862
1862
1862
1862
3736
3736
3736
3736
3736
3736
3736
3736
3736
3736
3736
3736
2526
2526
2526
2526
2526
2526
2526
2526
2526
2526
2526
2526
4774
4774
4774
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
4924
2598
2598
2598
2598
2598
2598
2598
2598
2598
2598
2598
2598
6705
6705
6705
6705
6705
6705
6705
6705
6705
6705
6705
6705
746
746
4760
4696
4760
4696
4760
4696
47701
47701
47701
47701
47701
47701
4744
4744
47701
47701
47701
47701
47701
47701
4778
4778
4778
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
4744
```

Why is it verifying the same vertex over and over and why isnt it getting into the goal? I'm using euclidian heuristic and it is taking really long and I have no idea why.

I really would appreciate any help since I'm struggling with this has been hours.

Best regards

My AStar algortithm:

```
template <class T>
void Graph<T>::aStar(const T &start, const T &goal, bool dist){

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < vertexSet.size(); i++) {
        vertexSet[i]->path = NULL;
        vertexSet[i]->distance = INF;
        vertexSet[i]->fx = INF;
        vertexSet[i]->closed = false;
        vertexSet[i]->inQueue = false;
    }

    Vertex<T> *s = vertexSet[addVertex(start)];

    s->setDistance(0);
    s->fx = s->getDistance() + heuristic_aStar(s, vertexSet[addVertex(goal)], dist);

    //priority_queue< VertexPtr<T>, vector< VertexPtr<T> >, CompareVertex<T> > nextVertices;

    vector<Vertex<T>*> pq;      //nextVertices


    pq.push_back(s);
    s->inQueue = true;

    //cout << s->getIntersection().getID() << endl;

    make_heap(pq.begin(), pq.end());

    while (!pq.empty()) {
        Vertex<T> *current = pq.front();
        pop_heap(pq.begin(), pq.end());
        pq.pop_back();

        current->inQueue = false;

        if (current == vertexSet[addVertex(goal)]){
            current->path = vertexSet[addVertex(goal)];
            break;
        }

        current->closed = true;

        for(unsigned i = 0; i < current->adj.size(); i++) {
            Edge<T> edge = current->adj[i];
            Vertex<T> *neighbour = edge.dest;

            double weight = dist ? edge.length : neighbour->time;

            if (!neighbour->closed) {
                neighbour->distance = current->distance + weight;
                neighbour->path = current;
                neighbour->fx = neighbour->distance + heuristic_aStar(neighbour, vertexSet[addVertex(goal)], dist);

                if(neighbour->inQueue)
                    removeFromQueue(pq, neighbour->getIntersection());
                else neighbour->inQueue = true;

                pq.push_back(vertexSet[addVertex(neighbour->getIntersection())]);

            }

            else if (current->distance + weight + heuristic_aStar(neighbour, vertexSet[addVertex(goal)], dist) < neighbour->fx){
                neighbour->closed = false;
                neighbour->distance = current->distance + weight;
                neighbour->path = current;
                neighbour->fx = neighbour->distance + heuristic_aStar(neighbour, vertexSet[addVertex(goal)], dist);

                pq.push_back(vertexSet[addVertex(neighbour->getIntersection())]);

                neighbour->inQueue = true;

            }

            cout << neighbour->path->getIntersection().getID() << endl;

            make_heap(pq.begin(), pq.end(), vertex_greater_than_fx<T>());

        }
    }

    cout << "PQ size: " << endl;
    cout << pq.size() << endl;

    for(unsigned i=0; i< pq.size(); i++){
        cout << pq[i]->getIntersection().getID() << endl;
    }

    return;
}
```

**AddVertex funcion**

```
template<class T>
inline int Graph<T>::addVertex(const T& in) {

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vertexSet.size(); i++){
        if(vertexSet[i]->getIntersection() == in)
            return i;
    }

    Vertex<T> *v = new Vertex<T>(in);
    vertexSet.push_back(v);

    return vertexSet.size();
}
```

**intersection class**

```
class Intersection {
    int id;
    Coordenadas coord;
    bool IP;
public:
    Intersection();
    Intersection (int ident, float x, float y);
    int getID() const;
    Coordenadas getCoord() const;
    void setIP(bool p);
    bool getIP();
    bool operator == (const Intersection &p2) const;
    bool operator != (const Intersection &p2) const;
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &os, Intersection &p);
};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve   -- emphasis on `minimal`

Comment: Could we see the implementation of `addVertex`? It is called frequently in `aStar`. On the face of it that seems wrong, but the comment by the declaration of `addVertex` suggests that it's meant to be OK to add a vertex that's already there -- but if anything is wrong in the implementation you could get multiple copies of a single vertex and that might produce repeated vertex IDs as seen in your output.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Just added AddVertex

Comment: Is the logic in the `!neighbour->closed` case correct? It says: if the neighbour is in the queue then remove it; otherwise set its in-the-queue flag; and then (*unconditionally*) put it into the queue. Is that what you were intending to do?

Comment: Add extra output statements to your program to figure out where it first diverges from the expected behaviour and why